# How to count the same words found in two different strings using php?

Tags: php

Say you have:

> $text1="i **can** wait **for all** night";
>
> $text2="we **can** sing **for all** day";

I need a function that will tell me 3 words found to be the same in both statements 
i.e `can`, `for`, `all`.

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$words1 = str_word_count($text1, 2);
$words2 = str_word_count($text2, 2);
$common_words = $result = array_intersect($words1, $words2);
$common_count = sizeof($common_words);
```

Comment: Thanks alot, interesting.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to get the array of words:

```
$text1="i can wait for all night"; 
$text2="we can sing for all day";
$text1arr = explode(" ", $text1);
$text2arr = explode(" ", $text2);
```

Then, you can use [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) to get the common words:

```
$result = array_intersect($text1arr , $text2arr);
```

Finally, you can use count to get the number of common words:

```
$num_in_common = [count][3]($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

As a heads up, SO is not a coding service, and people won't be happy when answers are simply asked for, with seemingly no effort on the part of the asker. However, here's a little bit to get you started.

The `array_intersect` function, when given two or more arrays, gives you an array of all of the values shared between the inputs.

As for finding the position of the values, the `array_search` function gives a key for a value in the array.

If all arrays share the same key for a value in the `array_intersect` output array, then you know that that value is shared by all arrays, and in the same position.

How to implement all this is up to you.